# Switch statements with identical control expressions but different case implementations

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have two switch statements that are identical in structure but the cases do different things. How do I possibly combine them? Or are there any better design suggestions instead of using two switch statements?

This is how the first switch statement looks:

```
switch(var){
   case 1:
    functionA();
   break;
   case 2:
    functionB();
   break;
}
```

The second looks like this:

```
switch(var){
   case 1:
    functionC();
   break;
   case 2:
    functionD();
   break;
}
```

Problem is, `functionA()` cannot be called at the same time with `functionC()` and same goes for `functionB()` and `functionD()` - they are to be called at different times.

Forgive me if this sounds silly, but is there a way to re-use one switch statement for different situations?

NB: This is not a "how do I do this?" question, but a "how do I do this *BETTER* question".

Comment: 1. Some more context would help. 2. If this is a "how do I do this BETTER" question, maybe [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) would be more appropriate

Comment: unless you are calling them in seperate threads a simple `functionA(); functionC();` will not run both methods **at the same time** but after each other. So I don't really understand what your problem is.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS the different switch statements are actually used at different times and from separate methods. I would like to "in theory" use only one switch statement

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca This question would get poor reception at Code Review due to it's hypothetical nature.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I'll keep it here for a while, maybe someone will understand... seems the downvote army has already arrived here. I wouldn't really call it hypothetical, but hey...maybe there's a 'constructor' for switch statements I have not heard about haha

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question), that may explain the downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

In my optionion there is no need to further simplify your switch statements, since they are readable and do different things. Also, in order to simplify you would need to add an additional layer of abstraction, which is not (really) possible here.

The only thing you could abstract here is the `var` parameter. Altough i would not recommend it, maybe you can try something like this:

```
private Consumer<Integer> createConsumer(Runnable... actions) {
    return i -> {
        if (actions.length < i)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        actions[i].run();
    };
}
```

You can create a consumer, which accepts an arbitary amount of `Runnable` objects

```
var consumer = createConsumer(
            () -> System.out.println("First"),
            () -> System.out.println("Second"),
            () -> System.out.println("Third"));
```

and execute it like

```
consumer.accept(0);
```

If you also need a default statement `Consumer<Integer> createConsumer(Runnable... actions, Runnable defaultOption)` could come to rescue, then the `IllegalArgumentException` would also be superfluous.

However, this would just be some functional style of `switch` statement, which could make things even more complicated, whenever the parameter does not start at 0, but some other number (you would need to subtract till 0) or if you switch block has "gaps" bewteen numbers (0, 1, 3, ...).